# I am not able to connect to any wifi network, It keeps asking me password

Tags: networking, wireless

Recently I installed rtl8822ce drivers from a source on github. After that whenever I try to connect to any wifi network and enter password, it doesnt connect to wifi.Please help me resolve this issue..
Below is the output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list`

```
01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:c82f]
        Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:c02f]
        Kernel driver in use: rtw_pci
        Kernel modules: rtwpci
0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
1: hci0: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: yes
        Hard blocked: no
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
3: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: What Ubuntu release? How did you "install ... from a source on github"? Are you typing the right password? CAPS LOCK? `sudo journalctl  -b 0 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager` will show some log messages.

Comment: I am currently using Kubuntu 19.10. I installed the drivers from https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new. Yeah I am typing the correct password every time and I am taking care of CAPSLOCK.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6 I have edited my answer as you told. Please have a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue which I posted about:

[Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Intel 7260 Wireless - won't connect to Wifi network](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1230922/ubuntu-20-04-lts-intel-7260-wireless-wont-connect-to-wifi-network)

Does the solution there help solve your problem?

It's not a full fix, because disabling 802.11n has some consequences in terms of speed, but it will allow you to at least connect to wifi.