# Ubuntu 20.04 cannot connect to wifi with frequency band 2.4Ghz

Tags: networking, wireless, ubuntu-drivers

I have a Dell laptop running Ubuntu 20.04. The wifi does not connect to a 2.4Ghz frequency band router (but can connect to 5Ghz).

After googling the problem, I tried setting the band to 2.4Ghz manually via the `nm-connection-editor` as recommended [here](https://zuoxingdong.github.io/post/2020-08-09-wifi-connection-problems-in-ubuntu/). This did not help.

The settings for the network are saved as you can see from here:

```
sudo cat /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/name.nmconnection
[connection]
id=name
uuid=*******
type=wifi
autoconnect-priority=1
interface-name=wlp2s0
permissions=

[wifi]
band=bg
mac-address-blacklist=
mode=infrastructure
ssid=name

[wifi-security]
key-mgmt=wpa-psk
psk=*******

[ipv4]
dns-search=
method=auto

[ipv6]
addr-gen-mode=stable-privacy
dns-search=
ip6-privacy=0
method=auto

[proxy]
```

I tried also restarting the network manager with `sudo service network-manager restart` and by restarting the laptop.

Do you have any suggestions on how to fix the problem? Any help would be really appreciated.

I include some additional information about my system:

```
sudo lshw -C network -sanitize
  *-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: BCM43602 802.11ac Wireless LAN SoC
       vendor: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlp2s0
       version: 01
       serial: [REMOVED]
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=brcmfmac driverversion=7.35.177.61 firmware=01-ea662a8c ip=[REMOVED] latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:143 memory:dd800000-dd807fff memory:dd400000-dd7fffff
```

```
lspci -vnn | grep -i net -A8
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM43602 802.11ac Wireless LAN SoC [14e4:43ba] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Dell BCM43602 802.11ac Wireless LAN SoC [1028:0020]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 143
    Memory at dd800000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=32K]
    Memory at dd400000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4M]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: brcmfmac
    Kernel modules: brcmfmac
```

```
sudo dmesg | grep brcm
[   12.679132] usbcore: registered new interface driver brcmfmac
[   12.679176] brcmfmac 0000:02:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[   12.784576] brcmfmac: brcmf_fw_alloc_request: using brcm/brcmfmac43602-pcie for chip BCM43602/1
[   12.787581] brcmfmac 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for brcm/brcmfmac43602-pcie.Dell Inc.-XPS 15 9550.txt failed with error -2
[   12.787600] brcmfmac 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for brcm/brcmfmac43602-pcie.txt failed with error -2
[   12.828507] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM20703A1-0a5c-6410.hcd failed with error -2
[   12.828509] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Patch brcm/BCM20703A1-0a5c-6410.hcd not found
[   13.322327] brcmfmac: brcmf_fw_alloc_request: using brcm/brcmfmac43602-pcie for chip BCM43602/1
[   13.322366] brcmfmac: brcmf_c_process_clm_blob: no clm_blob available (err=-2), device may have limited channels available
[   13.322852] brcmfmac: brcmf_c_preinit_dcmds: Firmware: BCM43602/1 wl0: Nov 10 2015 06:38:10 version 7.35.177.61 (r598657) FWID 01-ea662a8c
[   13.374104] brcmfmac 0000:02:00.0 wlp2s0: renamed from wlan0
[   23.092812] ieee80211 phy0: brcmf_inetaddr_changed: fail to get arp ip table err:-52
[   41.710983] ieee80211 phy0: brcmf_inetaddr_changed: fail to get arp ip table err:-52
[   75.081959] ieee80211 phy0: brcmf_inetaddr_changed: fail to get arp ip table err:-52
[  167.625935] ieee80211 phy0: brcmf_inetaddr_changed: fail to get arp ip table err:-52
[  178.201563] ieee80211 phy0: brcmf_inetaddr_changed: fail to get arp ip table err:-52
[  219.046639] ieee80211 phy0: brcmf_inetaddr_changed: fail to get arp ip table err:-52
[  378.890113] ieee80211 phy0: brcmf_inetaddr_changed: fail to get arp ip table err:-52
[  395.718585] ieee80211 phy0: brcmf_inetaddr_changed: fail to get arp ip table err:-52
[  429.483904] ieee80211 phy0: brcmf_inetaddr_changed: fail to get arp ip table err:-52
```

I read [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1230922/ubuntu-20-04-lts-intel-7260-wireless-wont-connect-to-wifi-network) that it is possible to add `options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1` to the  /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf file. I am unsure if this is the appropriate thing to do on my system. Is iwlwifi specific for Intel?

This is my current file:

```
cat /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf 
# /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
# iwlwifi will dyamically load either iwldvm or iwlmvm depending on the
# microcode file installed on the system.  When removing iwlwifi, first
# remove the iwl?vm module and then iwlwifi.
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211
```

As asked by Raffles I also add the output from iwlist chan:

```
iwlist chan
lo        no frequency information.

wlp2s0    32 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 12 : 2.467 GHz
          Channel 13 : 2.472 GHz
          Channel 34 : 5.17 GHz
          Channel 36 : 5.18 GHz
          Channel 38 : 5.19 GHz
          Channel 40 : 5.2 GHz
          Channel 42 : 5.21 GHz
          Channel 44 : 5.22 GHz
          Channel 46 : 5.23 GHz
          Channel 48 : 5.24 GHz
          Channel 52 : 5.26 GHz
          Channel 56 : 5.28 GHz
          Channel 60 : 5.3 GHz
          Channel 64 : 5.32 GHz
          Channel 100 : 5.5 GHz
          Channel 104 : 5.52 GHz
          Channel 108 : 5.54 GHz
          Channel 112 : 5.56 GHz
          Channel 116 : 5.58 GHz
          Channel 120 : 5.6 GHz
          Channel 124 : 5.62 GHz
          Current Frequency:5.24 GHz (Channel 48)

docker0   no frequency information.
```

Comment: Please show `iwlist chan` . Thank you.

Comment: "Is iwlwifi specific for Intel?" Yes. "I am unsure if this is the appropriate thing to do on my system. " No; you haven't an Intel device; yours is a Broadcom. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Is this a dual band 2.4 and 5 gHz router where the router and the wireless device and driver combination auto negotiate the fastest and most reliable connection? Why do you prefer the 2.4 gHz band?

Comment: Your device appears to working correctly by connecting to the best available channel. What router do you have?

Comment: Are you using a firewall?

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I have two separate routers. The one I cannot connect to is a Wi-fi range extender using 2.4Ghz frequency (specifications [here](https://www.tp-link.com/uk/home-networking/range-extender/tl-wa854re/#specifications)). I can easily connect with the main router with 5Ghz, but because the walls of the building are thick the signal is not very powerful. I do not have a firewall (```sudo ufw status``` returns inactive). Should I change the firewall?

Comment: Another stupid question, is your range extender compatible with your router? Your router appears to be `802.11 ac`, but at the link for your wireless extender it says `Works seamlessly with all 802.11 n/g/b wireless devices. It is also compatible with the latest Windows 8 operating system. `

Comment: thanks. Yes, the range extender does connect with another windows laptop I have and also with my phone

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest that if you have the means, to invest in a [Wifi Mesh system](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=best%20wifi%20mesh&t=brave&ia=web) which is more secure than the older systems and should solve your problem. Please make sure whatever system you choose can support a VPN, as some of them don't (such as mine which is a Velop and I regret it). It's favorable to have the entire home network pass through your favorite VPN, than individual machines. [VPN via router](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=advantages%20of%20router%20vpn&t=brave&ia=web)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I had a look at the wifi mesh + VPN (of which I was unaware. Thanks for pointing this out to me!). They indeed seem more reliable. The main drawback is the cost. Additionally, it would be nice to connect to 2.4Ghz frequencies if I travel, or do you think the issue I have now is specific to the wi-fi range I have?

Comment: @michela Can you go to a spot where it is not in range of the 5 GHz and see if it works there? Or possibly to someone else's router which is only 2.4 GHz? This might also be your router or range extender.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I ran the nm-connection-editor command and edited my 2.4GHz network.
In this tool you can force the use of the B/G(2.4GHz) band.
This solved my problem on Ubuntu 22.04. Wireless 7265.